# A good performance with n-fold cross validation and overfitting

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, overfitting

Is it possible to train a model (for regression or classification) that has overfitted but that has a good performance in a n-fold cross validation?

Comment: yes - for example if you have a small data set, or if the training / validation data set is not representative of the underlying distribution etc..

Comment: Apart from the case mentioned in the comment above, this situation could also happen by chance or by design, that is if the test data is very similar to the training data, say if you incorrectly sampled your sample (ex. non-random) and you get very similar subjects in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is meant by overfitting. If you take the definition to be that out-of-sample performance is terrible despite good in-sample performance, then such a definition precludes good performance by a model that has overfitting.

If, however, you take overfitting to mean that a simpler model would have better out-of-sample performance despite having worse in-sample performance, then good performance is still possible despite the overfitting. For example, consider the following image on the Wikipedia article on overfitting. Red is out-of-sample performance ($\epsilon$ stands for the "error"), while blue is in-sample performance.

[image]

Overfitting starts to occur to the right of the dotted line, as the red out-of-sample performance starts to worsen despite the blue in-sample performance getting better. However, just to the right of the dotted line represents the performance of a model that has overfit yet still performs rather well, even out-of-sample.

That is, models to the right of the dotted line have overfit. However, if "good" performance is defined as anything lower than the bottom of that triangle, then all models to the right of that dotted line have "good" performance, despite the overfitting.